# PlayerPrefs Equal to GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Working on a saving system in unity using c# code.
How can I obtain this kind of saving system.

In my empty `GameObject` I have a script and here it is:

**Counter.cs**

```
public int counter;
```

And that's all on my Counter.cs. Now how can I save and get it if it is inside of a `GameObject` . I just want to get the counter inside the Counter.cs.

Can I do it like this .

**SaveAndLoad.cs**

```
public GameObject SaveCounter;

public void Save(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", SaveCounter);
}

public void Load(){
    PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score"));
}
```

Can I do it something like that?

Comment: You shouldn't use `PlayerPrefs` to store any game progress and such. But if that's what you want then yes, you can do it somewhat like that.

Comment: Like @m.rogalski said. It's not 'the-way-to-go'. I believe Unity recommends using a scriptable object for this and save that. ScriptableObjects can be saved to assets :). Or write your own custom gamesave file.

Comment: @m.rogalski so i can do it like this 
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", SaveCounter<counter>());

PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score");

Comment: @TheGinxx009 What are you trying to accomplish? Just checking if the syntax works or if it is the 'proper' way to do that. If it is the first then you're better of just testing your code and see if it works. If the latter then change your question to reflect this.

Comment: @Measuring I'm trying to get the proper way on how to do it sir .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question

**YOU SHOULD NOT STORE GAME STATE RELATED THINGS IN PLAYER PREFS**

Instead you can make serializable object :

```
[Serializable]
public class GameState
{
    int m_Score;

    public int Score 
    {
        get { return m_Score; }
        set { m_Score = value; }
    }
}
```

Then use a `BinaryFormatter` and some helper object to serialize this data into a file :

```
public void StoreGameState(GameState state)
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("./gamestate.bin")))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
        formatter.Serialize(state, writer);
    }
}

public GameState RestoreGameState()
{
    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("./gamestate.bin")))
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter()
        return (GameState)formatter.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

Then add `GameState` to your empty `GameObject` :

```
public GameState CurrentProgress;
```

And read whenever you want to save or load use the two methods I've posted : `StoreGameState` and `RestoreGameState`.

But if you're really into storing these kind of data in `PlayerPrefs` then you can still do :

```
public GameObject SaveCounter;

public void Save(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player Score", SaveCounter.GetComponentn<Counter>().counter);
}

public void Load(){
    SaveCounter.GetComponentn<Counter>().counter = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player Score"));
}
```

Which is not recommended by anyone.

Comment: why is it not recommended sir ?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 1. `PlayerPrefs` can only store a few types (int, float, string). 2. You have no control over where the data is saved. 3. No control over how the data is interpreted (you need to write a wrapper for it). 4. `PlayerPrefs` is for player preferences not player progression. Use `PlayerPrefs` if you want to hide a tutorial window after the user first saw it (for example).

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Because it's not a persistent file. It's basically different for each platform and for Windows it uses registry which is never a good idea to write into.

Comment: So my playerprefs won't work if i make my game as a .exe? what platfrom does playerprefs work . does it work on .apk files ?

Comment: @TheGinxx009 That was an example on where it will be stored on windows os. It will work on every device but It's main purpose is to store some simple informations like screen resolution, language flag, etc. You can read more about `PlayerPrefs` [in here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Comment: Thank you so much sir . You helped me a lot. @m.rogalski